# GIF image support in android

Tags: java, android, gif

```
GifMovieView.java

public class GifMovieView extends View
{

private Movie mMovie;    
private InputStream mStream;
public GifMovieView(Context context, InputStream stream)
{         
    super(context);         
    mStream = stream;         
    mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(mStream);  

}
private long mMoviestart;

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
{
   canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
   super.onDraw(canvas);

   final long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

   if (mMoviestart == 0)
   {
      mMoviestart = now;
   }

   final int relTime = (int)((now - mMoviestart) % mMovie.duration());
   mMovie.setTime(relTime);
   mMovie.draw(canvas, 10,  10);
   this.invalidate();
}
```

}

Activitiy

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    InputStream stream = null; 
    try { 
        stream = getAssets().open("splash.gif");
    } catch (IOException e)
    { e.printStackTrace(); } 
    GifMovieView view = new GifMovieView(this, stream);
    setContentView(view);

}
```

I am trying to suport a Gif image as my splash screen in an android application .Using GifMovieView i was also able to support it but with a small flaw i.e the image is animating but its not covering the entire screen .Please HELP!

[image]

Comment: If the gif is working fine on splash screen please show your xml layout code

Comment: Doesn have any XML layout . GifMovieView object forms my layout which extends View class

Comment: [Did you try one demo](https://github.com/sbakhtiarov/gif-movie-view/tree/master/src/com/basv/gifmoviewview/widget)

Comment: trying is worth, isn't it?

Comment: yes, trying since last night

Comment: @LalitPoptani what is R.styleable.GifMoviewView_paused in the code

Comment: @LalitPoptani where is the styleable folder ??

Comment: try set your GifMovieView to match_parent?